Adding video tag to react-quill editor
I'm trying to add video handler into my quill editor and it working. However, I want to add capability to prevent video download like <video> tag did. Here's my code
 const videoHandler = () => {
    if (quillRef.current) {
      const editor = quillRef.current.getEditor();
      if (editor) {
        var range = editor.getSelection();
        var value = prompt('Please paste the video URL here.');
        if (value) {
          if (value.includes('myService.com')) {
            editor.insertEmbed(range.index, 'video', value, 'user');
          } else {
            alert('Only videos from myService.com domain are allowed.');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

My attempt is tried to inser <video> tag directly like this
const videoTag = <video width="100%" min-height="400px" controls controlsList="nodownload"> <source src="${value}" type="video/mp4"> </video> ;
const delta = editor.clipboard.convert({ html: videoTag });

It's not working and I'm getting [Violation] 'click' handler took 521ms warning.
